# Static extension method in TypeScript the right way

Tags: typescript

We all know the "hackish" way to craft extension methods in TypeScript:

```
declare global {
  interface Map<K, V> {
    getOrSet(key: K, create: () => V): V;
  }
}

Map.prototype.getOrSet = function (key: any, create: () => any) {
  let v = this.get(key);
  if (v === undefined) {
    this.set(key, (v = create()));
  }
  return v;
};

const songs = new Map<string, Set<string>>();
songs.getOrSet("The Killers", () => new Set<string>()).add("Mr. Brightside");
```

However, I don't like this approach since it's very intrusive with global side effects.

An alternative would be to mixin the behaviour into a single instance:

```
interface MapWithGetOrSet<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  getOrSet(key: K, create: () => V): V;
}

function withGetOrSet<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>): MapWithGetOrSet<K, V> {
  (map as MapWithGetOrSet<K, V>).getOrSet = function (key: K, create: () => V) {
    let v = this.get(key);
    if (v === undefined) {
      this.set(key, (v = create()));
    }
    return v;
  };
  return map as MapWithGetOrSet<K, V>;
}
```

Not much better...

It's 2020 and even Dart nowadays has static extension methods. So, my question is:

**Is there a way to create real/scoped static extension methods in TypeScript 4.x?**

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you find "hackish" about this solution. It is the JS (and inherently, the typescript way) of doing stuff. It is perfectly clean, and will extend your object only if you import the file that has implemented the extension. Furthermore, an extension is that - an extension - it won't interfere with the workings of the underlying object in 99.9% of the cases (only case I can think of is if two libraries try to apply the same extension, but you should be getting a compiler error for such a case.

Yes, this way of doing things is baffling for a person coming from strongly-typed languages, but in typescript, this is not an issue.

Finally, if you're worried about polluting the global scope, perhaps extension methods aren't the concept for you to begin with. Extension methods by design will pollute the global scope, regardless of the language they're used in.